# How to show that $(2, \sqrt{82})$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{82}]$ is not pricipal?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I tried the obvious things, like using the norm and trying to show that there were no integer solutions to $a^2 - 82b^2 = 2$, but didn't get anywhere.

(A friend asked me this.)

Comment: I bet you can show there are no integer solutions to that equation. Difference of squares?

Comment: If that's a principal ideal, it can be generated by a single number, e.g., $\langle 8, \sqrt{-2} \rangle$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$.

Answer (score 1):

The equation $$a^2-82b^2=2$$ can be checked for solutions over the integers
by applying continued fractions. See this link :

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PellEquation.html

Comment: There was a typo in the norm equation I wrote down.

Comment: The condition $|c|<\sqrt{D}$ is met in your case.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: the least background possible here is to look up the continued fraction for $\sqrt {n^2 +1}$ and find out how that relates to values of $x^2 - (n^2 +1)y^2$ of small absolute value.

From Henri Cohen book: the primes represented by $x^2 - 82 y^2$ are precisely those $p$ for which
$$ z^4 - 2 z^3 - 3 z^2 + 2 z + 1  \equiv 0 \pmod p  $$
has four distinct roots. Those primes up to $4000$ are

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./count_roots
    73   103   113   223   359   401   449   487   569   617
   631   647   743   761   769  1087  1103  1193  1231  1279
  1289  1303  1321  1439  1471  1583  1601  1607  1609  1663
  1697  1993  1999  2089  2111  2153  2273  2287  2377  2383
  2399  2417  2423  2543  2591  2647  2657  2663  2711  2767
  2833  2903  2927  3167  3361  3449  3527  3559  3617  3727
  3767  3793  3833  3967
```

ORIGINAL: As it happens, there is no solution to $x^2 - 82 y^2 = 2.$ The most familiar method for proving that would be continued fractions; the Gauss-Lagrange method deals with reduced quadratic forms:

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./Pell 82


0  form   1 18 -1   delta  -18
1  form   -1 18 1   delta  18
2  form   1 18 -1

 disc   328
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
1  18
18  325


 Pell automorph 
163  1476
18  163

Pell unit 
163^2 - 82 * 18^2 = 1
```

The class number is four. The class number is the same as the number of classes of quadratic forms of this discriminant, because the principal form $x^2 - 82 y^2$ also represents $-1,$ as $81-82 = -1.$ Overview at http://math.blogoverflow.com/2014/08/23/binary-quadratic-forms-over-the-rational-integers-and-class-numbers-of-quadratic-%EF%AC%81elds/

```
328    factored   2^3 *  41

    1.             1          18          -1   cycle length             2
    2.             2          16          -9   cycle length             6
    3.             3          16          -6   cycle length             6
    4.             6          16          -3   cycle length             6

  form class number is   4
```